# Powering off a Lucent 8400B

Tags: power-supply-unit

Will powering off a Lucent 8400B-L3 Data Service Unit hurt anything? Will it lose any data, etc.?

I'm having a problem connecting my BCMS Server to the data module. I keep getting a "call not completed" error. I double checked the netcon hunt group number and it is correct and working. Everything worked fine until the power switched off earlier today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was so impatient I decided to try it without any answers. In my case, none of the profiles were reset, and the BCMS server connected back to the switch fine.